# Conversion from 'size_t' to 'T' Requires a Narrowing Conversion - Class Template

Tags: c++, class, c++20, class-template

I'm trying solve Exercise 17-1 in "Beginning C++20: from invoice to professional" by Ivor Horton. It ask me to implement a "push_back()" function (resembles the one in std::vector) in the self-defined template class "MyArray".

The following is the class template:

```
export module myArray;

import <initializer_list>;
import <stdexcept>;
import <utility>;

export template <typename T>
class MyArray
{
    public:

        MyArray();                                          // Default constructor
        MyArray(size_t size);                               // Constructor
        // MyArray(std::initializer_list<T> elements);       // List initializer constructor
        MyArray(const MyArray& another);                    // Copy constructor

        ~MyArray();                                         // Destructor

        MyArray& operator = (const MyArray& another);       // Copy assignment

        T& operator [] (size_t index);                      // Subscript operator
        const T& operator [] (size_t index) const;          // Subscript operator on const-array

        size_t getSize() const;                             // Getter

        void swap(MyArray& other) noexcept;                 // For copy-and-swap idiom

        void push_back(const T& newElement);                // Add new element to the array


    private:
        T* m_elements;
        size_t m_size;
};
```

The following are the implementation of the list initializer constructor and push_back() function:

```
template <typename T>
MyArray<T>::MyArray(std::initializer_list<T> elements)
    : m_elements { new T[elements.size()] }, m_size { elements.size() }
{
    for (size_t i { 0 }; const T & element : elements)
    {
        m_elements[i] = element;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

```
template <typename T>
void MyArray<T>::push_back(const T& newElement)
{
    MyArray<T> copy { m_size + 1 };

    for (size_t i { 0 }; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        copy[i] = m_elements[i];
    }

    copy[m_size] = newElement;

    swap(copy);
}
```

I'm testing this template with:

```
import myArray;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    const unsigned numElements { 100 };

    MyArray<unsigned int> squares;       // default construction

    for (unsigned i {}; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        squares.push_back(i * i);    // push_back()
    }


    std::cout << squares.getSize() << " squares were added." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "For instance: 13 squared equals " << squares[13] << std::endl;
}
```

Other member functions are working fine.

However, when I uncomment the List initializer constructor, the compiler will raise
an error `C298 - Element '1': conversion from size_t to 'T' requires a narrowing conversion`

and a warning `C4267 - conversion from 'size_t' to 'T', possible loss of data` on "push_back()".

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in a single code block. Please post the complete error messages with the notes.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to test collections with elements that can't be confused with sizes or indices. `MyArray<std::string>` would probably give a better error message.

Comment: @273K Thank you so much! I do apologize this is only the second time I post a question, will do so next time.

Comment: @molbdnilo Duly noted！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyArray<T> copy { m_size + 1 };` If you uncomment the constructor with the initializer list, then it will be chosen in the `copy` declaration, `T` is `unsigned int` and `size_t` will possibly loose data. If you want to use the constructor with the `size_t` parameter, then declare the `MyArray<T> copy(m_size + 1);`.

See the similar [std::vector notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector#Notes).

> Note that the presence of list-initializing constructor means list initialization and direct initialization do different things